# DMAR Firmware Bug - No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR - what does this mean?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, ssd

I recently installed a new mSATA 512GB SSD into a Lenovo ThinkPad X220 i5 - I installed Xubuntu 22.04 onto it successfully, and I can even boot into Xubuntu and it works fine (I'm even writing this post in Xubuntu) - however, when choosing to boot to my mSATA SSD (I have Windows 10 22H2 installed on my 2.5' 1 TB SATA SSD) so I can boot into Xubuntu, I get this error at the start:

`[ 0.092860] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR [0x00000000db800000-0x00000000df9fffff] contact BIOS vendor for fixes /dev/sdc3: clean, 231409/31227904 files, 6550078/124894976 blocks`

I have searched high and low on the internet and no one seems to know what this is - my BIOS works fine and I can reconfigure it, boot into Windows or Xubuntu etc.

**My bios version is: 8DET56WW (1.26)**

Pastebin with my Xubuntu system info: https://pastebin.com/3Uw3s4er

To provide more background context, here is a link to a Reddit post I made about a Windows 10 issue I had after installing Xubuntu, now fixed (sort of): https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/19c4ia0/cannot_boot_into_windows_10_22h2_on_thinkpad_x220/

Thanks.